# Restrict login to specific domain using Node Passport with Google Auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am implementing Google Auth on an internal service at work. It is a JS client heavy application with a Node backend. I am choosing to use the Node module Passport.js with the passport-google-oauth strategy.

I have successfully got it working but one thing is still confusing me. I want to ensure my application allows only company employees to login. I understand that you can restrict the login by domain using a parameter called "hd", [according to the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#sendauthrequest).

Firstly, where do you send that parameter in the context of Passport.js? I just don't understand where in the code that is put. If it helps, I have been mostly following [the example passport-google-oauth provides](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/blob/master/examples/oauth2/app.js).

Secondly, in theory how does this all work? Is it on the Google side, where they reject anyone trying to access the app with a domain outside of our company. Or is it on my side, that I need to check what domain the user is logging in from?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
// first make sure you have access to the proper scope on your login route
app.get("/login", passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
}));

// set up your Google OAuth strategy elsewhere...
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: "something",
    clientSecret: "something",
    callbackURL: "/something"
}, function(token, refreshToken, profile, done){
    if(profile._json.hd === "yourdomain.com"){
        // find or create user in database, etc
        User.find({ id: profile.id }).done(done);
    }else{
        // fail        
        done(new Error("Invalid host domain"));
    }
});
```

And for good measure here's a full variable dump of what the "profile" variable looks like.

```
{ 
    provider: 'google',
    id: '12345678987654321',
    displayName: 'Don Draper',
    name: { familyName: 'Whitman', givenName: 'Richard' },
    emails: [ { value: 'don@scdp.com' } ],
    _raw: 'a bunch of stringified json',
    _json: { 
        id: '123456789',
        email: 'something@something.com',
        verified_email: true,
        name: 'Don Draper',
        given_name: 'Don',
        family_name: 'Draper',
        link: 'https://plus.google.com/123456789',
        picture: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/123456789/photo.jpg',
        gender: 'male',
        locale: 'en',
        hd: 'yourdomain.com' 
    } 
}
```

Here are some detailed tutorials that should answer your question about the theory behind all of this. You'll want some combination of the two.

1. [Local authentication and basic setup](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local)
2. [Google authentication](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-google)

Comment: `profile._json.hd` seems to now be `profile._json.domain`

Answer (score 13):

I recommend a 2 step approach to this. Would love to hear feedback if this is overcomplicating it.

### 1) Help your users pick the right account

```
passport.authenticate('google', {
    // Only show accounts that match the hosted domain.
    hd: 'example.com',
    // Ensure the user can always select an account when sent to Google.
    prompt: 'select_account',
    scope: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
    ]
})(req, res, next);
```

### 2) Validate their profile

When a user is sent to `accounts.google.com` to authenticate, there is a simple `hd=example.com` query parameter in the URL. You can remove this and authenticate with any account (Passport will successfully verify the Oauth code regardless of the domain of the chosen account), so it should only be considered sugar for the end user and not security for the server.

When Passport *does* resolve the authentication, just check the hosted domain as in aembke's answer:

```
passport.use(new google_strategy({
    clientID: ...
    clientSecret: ...
    callbackURL: ...
}, function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

    if (profile._json.domain !== 'example.com') {
        done(new Error("Wrong domain!"));
    } else {
        done(null, profile);
    }

}));
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie! it works with me using passport-google-oauth2